# Amount of rows in UITableview with sections

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, uitableview

i got a UITableview with sections.

The sections are handled by Core Data's NSFetchResultsController, however this is less important concerning my problem.

I'd like to have a predefined amount of rows in my UITableview. Let say i start the application, i'd like to see only 10 rows, even if i got 14 entries in Core Data. When i click a button "load more.." the next 10 rows should be loaded (loading is implemented i just need to figure out a way to display the right amount of rows). If i got 10 rows at the beginning and in the first section are 7 and in the second are 5 then the last two rows of the second section should not be display until i click the load more button to show the next 10. So i think i have to implement this logic in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` but i need a hint from you how to solve this...

Basically i would need a loop which loops through the sections. If the amount of rows i want to display is reached i return all sections until this point to be displayed. Then i would need to retrieve all the rows of this sections and the rows of the sections before to calculate the numberOfRowsInSection for each section...

Anyway somebody who can help me implement this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a good way to solve this is to use the fetched results controller. You can try setting the `fetchLimit` on the fetched results controller's `fetchRequest`. If the sorting of your FRC is correct, it should retrieve the first `n` objects.

```
-(void)loadRows:(NSUInteger)numberOfRows {
   NSFetchRequest *request = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest; 
   request.fetchLimit = numberOfRows;
   NSError *error;
   [self.fetchedResultsController executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! i did not thought about this. Works like a charm.